# django urlconf 404 on webroot

Tags: python, regex, django

- Django: 1.8.5
- Python: 3.5

I'm getting a 404 on just the webroot. I don't know what's wrong with my `urlconf`.

Directory structure:

```
myproject        // from django-admin startproject
  myproject      // ''                          ''
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    views.py
  myapp          // from manage.py startapp
    migrations
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

In myproject > urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from myapp import urls as app_urls


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/$', include(app_urls)),
)
```

And in myapp > urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/$', 'index'),
)
```

I run the django development server and I get a 404 on the index page, even though I have the empty regex defined.

```
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^/$
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

The documentation in `urls.conf` from a a fresh install of django:

```
Including another URLconf
    1. Add an import:  from blog import urls as blog_urls
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls))
```

Changing the regex in BOTH urls.py files to `r'^'` appears to work, but with a new `'Could not import 'index'.` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root URL is `^$`, not `^/$`.

Also, when you include a urlconf from another urlconf, it uses both patterns together; it doesn't forget the original pattern.  So your app is really looking for the url `^/$^/$`, which I'm not sure can ever be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$`, when using `include`. Change it to:

```
# myproject/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from myapp import urls as app_urls


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(app_urls)),
)

# myapp/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working for me. Chrome gives this as the url it tried `^/` and it's still not working.

Comment: Changing the regex in both urls.py files to `r'^'` seems to work, with a new `could not import index` error.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, that was missing. Thanks

Comment: Change the view from `'index'` to  `'myapp.views.index'`, or even better, add the import `from . import views`, then change the view to `views.index` (no quotes).